# what is the best cross-platform library for read data from USB port?

Tags: c, usb

I'm looking for a cross-platform library for read data from USB port.  The library must be compatible with Linux and Windows systems; best performance, I want to send data instant mode(using http protocol).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that would be libusb, although http over USB is a little... quirky.

Comment: @awoodland: Depends on the viewpoint. If you are the owner of a USB-based WLAN device, you essentially do http (over IP over Ethernet over 802.11) over USB most of the day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your device uses HID, try [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi). If it's not HID, use [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/)